# Any Statistical or Machine Learning Method to Predict Salary

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I am working on FinTech company. We are providing loan for our customers. Customers who want to apply for loan must fill in some information in our app and one of the information is salary information. Using webscraping we are able to grab our customers' bank transaction data for last 3-7 last months.

Using any statistic or machine learning technique how can I easily spot if the salary amount (or pretty much same) stated in customers bank transaction data? Should I make one model (logic) for each customer or it should be only one model apply for all customers?

Please advise

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need machine learning for this.

1. Out of the list of all transaction, keep only those that add money to the account, rather than subtract money from the account
2. Round all numbers to a certain accuracy (e.g. 2510 USD -> 2500 USD)
3. Build a dataset that contains the total amount added to the account for each day. In other words, group transactions by day, and add 0's wherever needed
4. Apply a discrete Fourier transform to find the periodic components in this time-series
5. There should only be 1 periodic item, repeating every 30ish days
6. Set the values of all other periodically repeating items to 0
7. Apply inverse discrete Fourier transform to get only that information that repeats every 28/30 days

For more information on the Fourier transform, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform

For a practical example (using MatLab),
check out
https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/fft-for-spectral-analysis.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

It shows how to give a frequency decomposition of a time-signal. If you apply the same logic, you can use this frequency decomposition to figure out which frequencies are dominant (typically the salary will be one of them).

Comment: Hi Joris, 

Thank you for your response. But I am not sure about point no 3. What is "group transactions by day" means? Is that just cluster it or something else?

Please advise

Comment: Updated my post to include further example.